# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/lib/pgadmin/azurecredentialcache'

Tags: python, postgresql, installation, pgadmin-4

I have been trying to install pgadmin4 on my linux os using the python package but when I try running the python script "python3 lib/python3.9/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py" it brings the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/gentle/pgAdmin4/pgAdmin4/bin/pgadmin4", line 5, in <module>
    from pgadmin4.pgAdmin4 import main

  File "/home/gentle/pgAdmin4/pgAdmin4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py", line 93, in <module>
    app = create_app()

  File "/home/gentle/pgAdmin4/pgAdmin4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgadmin/__init__.py", line 270, in create_app
    create_app_data_directory(config)

  File "/home/gentle/pgAdmin4/pgAdmin4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgadmin/setup/data_directory.py", line 117, in create_app_data_directory
    _create_directory_if_not_exists(config.AZURE_CREDENTIAL_CACHE_DIR)

  File "/home/gentle/pgAdmin4/pgAdmin4/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgadmin/setup/data_directory.py", line 20, in _create_directory_if_not_exists
    os.mkdir(_path)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/lib/pgadmin/azurecredentialcache'
```

What should I do?

Comment: Check out this thread.  It seems to be another guy having the same problem, and there's a proposed solution:  https://9to5answer.com/how-to-install-pgadmin-4-in-desktop-mode-on-ubuntu.   BTW, why the `postgresql` tag ?

Comment: Thanks so much I found the solution there

Answer (score 2):

Normally what you find around in the internet is to create the `lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4/config_local.py` file with the following content:

```
import os

DATA_DIR = os.path.realpath(os.path.expanduser(u'~/.pgadmin/'))
LOG_FILE = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'pgadmin4.log')
SQLITE_PATH = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'pgadmin4.db')
SESSION_DB_PATH = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'sessions')
STORAGE_DIR = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'storage')
SERVER_MODE = False
```

Just add the following line to fix the problem:

```
AZURE_CREDENTIAL_CACHE_DIR = os.path.join(DATA_DIR, 'azurecredentialcache')
```